# Angular 7 router.navigate() queryParams - parsing multiple values for the same param

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular7

So, basicaly I have a route to which I have to pass a few values, but they are all regarding the same parameter. This is the URL I wish to navigate to:

> http://localhost:4200/home/path?status=1&status=5

I tried to set the routing through router.navigate(), but this is not allowed since it's regarding the same parameter (An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name):

```
this.router.navigate(["/home/path"], {
      queryParams: { status: '1', status: '5'},
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any advices and suggestions

Comment: Hello. You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893216/specifying-multiple-values-for-a-parameter-in-angular

Comment: I would suggest to think about your parameters. Why do you have two parameters with the same name?

Comment: @derstauner This is because on the route it accesses there's a method to search and filter according to these parameters. There are other options to filter, but they are just simple values. The Status on the other hand is some form of an array. Meaning I need to be able to send more than one value.

Given that, if I can't find a solution, I'll move on to creating individual parameters, as you mentioned. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was pretty much under my nose, as I replied to @derstauner:

I can pass the queryParams as an array. So simply by stating that status=[1,5], the redirecting works fine:

```
this.router.navigate(["/home/path"], {
      queryParams: { status: [1,5]},
    });
```